# NestJs ClassValidator validate from DB using generic entity

Tags: generics, dependency-injection, nestjs, typeorm, class-validator

I want to validate a field in Dto to check that if it exists in database, for that I am creating a custom decorator.

Here's my Dto

```
export default class MyDto {
 @IsNotEmpty({ message: 'Email is required' })
 @IsEmail({}, { message: 'Email must be a valid email' })
 @Exists<Users>('id', { message: 'Email is invalid' })
 email: string;
}
```

Here's my custom decorator code

```
export function Exists<T extends Object>(columnName: keyof T, validationOptions?: ValidationOptions) {
    return function (object: Object, propertyName: string) {
        registerDecorator({
            target: object.constructor,
            propertyName: propertyName,
            constraints: [columnName],
            options: validationOptions,
            validator: ExistsValidation<T>
        });
    };
}
```

and Here's my validation code

```
@ValidatorConstraint({ name: 'Exists', async: true })
@Injectable()
export class ExistsValidation<T extends Object> implements ValidatorConstraintInterface {
    constructor(
        @InjectRepository(T)
        private readonly repository: Repository<T>
    ) { }

    async validate(value: any, args: ValidationArguments): Promise<boolean> {
        const [columnName] = args.constraints;
        
        return await this.repository.findOne(
            { where: { [columnName]: value } }
        ) ? true : false;
    }
}
```

But the issue is **@InjectRepository** does not take type instead it takes **EntityClassOrSchema** but I can't understand how to pass it in there.

Working on this problem for two days any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the solution instead of injecting Repository I injected the dataSource

```
constructor(
    private readonly connection: DataSource
) { }
```

Like this and then use it to create QueryRunner and use it for query like this

```
const queryRunner = this.connection.createQueryRunner();
const result = await queryRunner.query(query);
```